# instanceof operator gives negative result when using different library version

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 projects: `my-server` which is a server application and `my-lib` which is a package.
`my-server` is dependent on `my-lib` and both of them are dependent on some external lib from npm registry called `external-lib@1.0.0`.

`external-lib` exports `HttpException` (extends plain JS `Error` class) which is thrown by `my-server` and handled by `my-lib`.
`my-server` may throw different errors and `my-lib` should handle all of them gracefully and what `my-lib` does under the hood is:

```
import { HttpException } from 'external-lib'

const handler = (captured: unknown) => {
  if (captured instanceof HttpException) {
    // do some logic
  } else {
    // do another logic
  }
}
```

And it works just fine until I version bump `external-lib` to `2.0.0` only in `my-server`, and not in `my-lib`. If I do that then this condition `captured instanceof HttpException` returns `false` in `my-lib`.
And what is unclear to me - **why it fails?** I noticed that `HttpException` was not modified in `external-lib` since `1.0.0`

Comment: If there are two different library versions, then that means there are two different `HttpException` constructor functions. A given object can only be an instance of one of them.

Comment: @Pointy this makes sense, thank you. What is unclear is that how does the runtime understand that constructor functions are different when versions are different and vice versa?

Comment: @RustyGold   There in different packages, a version 1.0.0 code will be another instance compared to version 1.0.1

Comment: To help understand, look at this code -> `class A{}; const makeA2 = new class A{}; console.log(makeA2 instanceof A, new A instanceof A)`   You will see it returns `false true`, and not `true true`

Comment: @Keith thank you! Is there a way for me to check if captured value is `HttpException` from `external-lib`? Without using `instanceof`

Comment: Mixing versions in one app is usually not a good idea.   But you could make check the `constructor.name` , eg.   `if (captured.constructor.name === 'HttpException') { .... }`